# Configure python interpreter with docker compose error "python script path must be set"

Tags: debugging, docker-compose, pycharm, interpreter

Python django Project runs on docker-compose and i need to create run/Debug configuration an followed official documentation
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Upon clicking run or debug getting error "Python script path must be set"

OS: macOS version 12.4
docker compose: 2.6.1
Pycharm professional

Comment: did you solve this I am facing same issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Late, but for those who come here: Chances are you have renamed your project folder in Pycharm. It seems that Pycharm fails to adjust the django settings.

[image]

Set the new Django project root and also select the proper settings file, this has fixed it for me.